# Understand pts/1 services on LINUX or AIX systems

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am trying to kill all the `java` processes which are running by a particular user. Then I want to check if all the `java` services are stopped successfully or not and based on that I want to perform certain steps. In my script I used

```
ps -fu user_name | grep java | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill -9`
```

and check if `echo $?` returns `0`.

I tried to run the following commands manually on my Linux/AIX servers:

```
ps -fu user_name | grep java
```

and it returned

```
user_name      31970 31630  0 11:06 pts/1    00:00:00 grep java
```

After that I did `echo $?`  it returned`0`. Next, I tried to kill the `java` services by executing the following command:

```
ps -fu user_name | grep java | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill -9
```

and it gave `kill 32230: No such process`. `echo $?` returned `123` instead of `0`.

Can someone please explain what's going on and how can I make sure that all `java` processes are killed successfully (its okay if `pts/1` is alive)?

Comment: Did any answer help you? Let me know if you need more help.

Comment: Thanks for following up. I can not use `pkill` or `killall` in my script as per the requirements so I am using `ps -fu user_name | grep java | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill -9` as recommended by @Barmar.

Answer (score 3):

As you can see in your second command, `grep java` is matching the `grep` process itself, because it has `java` in its arguments. But by the time `kill` runs, `grep` has finished, so you can't kill it.

There are two common ways to resolve this. One is to filter out `grep`:

```
ps -fu user_name | grep java | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill -9
```

The other is to use a trick:

```
ps -fu user_name | grep '[j]ava` | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill -9
```

This prevents the `grep` command from matching itself, because the argument contains extra `[]` characters, so it doesn't match the pattern.

Note that most Linux distributions have `killall` and/or `pkill` commands, which allow you to kill processes by name, so you shouldn't need to code this yourself.

Answer (score 1):

As [@Barman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1491895/barmar) suggested, you can use `pkill` or `killall` and if you have it in your system, that's definitively the best options instead of the more expensive pipeline.

#### Using [`pkill`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pkill)

With [`pkill`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pkill) you can send a signal to all the process matching a *pattern*.

> pattern:
>   Specifies an Extended Regular Expression for matching against the process names or command lines.

```
pkill -u user_name -9 java
```

*Note: Previously to execute `pkill` you can check the pids to be killed with `pgrep`*

#### Getting the pids with [`pgrep`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pgrep)

You can firstly check the *matched* pids with [`pgrep`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pgrep) as follows:

```
pgrep -u user_name java
```

and if you don't care about the performance (why not?), you can pipe those pids and send them a signal with `xargs` as you do:

```
pgrep -u user_name java | xargs kill -9
```

or you can do the same with [Command Substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Substitution):

```
kill -9 $(pgrep -u user_name java)
```

#### Using [`killall`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/killall)

Alternatively to `pkill`, you can use [`killall`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/killall). `killall` doesn't match the names by *Extended regular expressions* by default as `pkill` does. So, if you want to simulate a nearer behaviour to `pkill`, you must specify the `-r` option:

```
killall -r -u user_name -9 java
```

#### Checking success

Suppose you chose `pkill` to send the signal to the processes. If you want to perform certain steps if your command succeed, you can simply put it into an `if` statement:

```
if pkill -u user_name -9 java; then
    step_1
    step_2
fi
```